# What does v-on="..." syntax mean in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I came across a Vuetify example for the [v-dialog component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#usage) which has the scoped slot called activator defined as follows:

```html
<template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
  <v-btn
    color="red lighten-2"
    dark
    v-on="on"
  >
    Click Me
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

I understand the purpose of [scoped slots from VueJS docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) and the concept of [destructuring slot props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props) but I don't understand what the meaning of `v-on="on"` is in this example. In particular what it means when the event is not specified with the `v-on` directive?

The [VueJS docs on `v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) only show its usage in combination with an event name explicitly specified (eg. `v-on:click="..."`) but there is no explanation of just using it as `v-on="..."`.

Can someone explain this syntax and its usage in the Vuetify example?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on : <!-- object syntax (2.4.0+) -->
<button v-on="{ mousedown: doThis, mouseup: doThat }"></button>

Comment: @Estradiaz please post that as an answer

Comment: @adiga That's the answer. However, the OP is asking to explain how it is used in the mentioned example, where `on` is not defined anywhere other than in the activator and is used in `v-on`.

Comment: @briosheje `on` is probably a property of `data` of that component? (Not that familiar with vue btw)

Comment: @adiga I'm not familiar either, but I don't think a simple link to the documentation actually helps, since if you take a look at the example it's still unclear how "on" works in that context.

Comment: @briosheje i extended the link to some insight - are there still some open issues i can add? or is something unclear - syntax/context? thx

Comment: @adiga its not a property of `data` its passed in `render` to a `scopedslot[name]({[key]: value}) `

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### [TLDR:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)

#### basic usage

> ```
> <!-- object syntax (2.4.0+) --> 
> <button v-on="{ mousedown: doThis, mouseup: doThat }"></button>]
> ```

So basically `@click="..."` equals `v-on:click="..."` equals `v-on="{click:...}"`

---

### [TLDR:](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3beea7c9107da273465b0d65f4cde3f8fbc1b7bc/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/activatable/index.ts#L81)

#### vuetify implementation:

> ```
> genActivator () {
>       const node = getSlot(this, 'activator', Object.assign(this.getValueProxy(), {
>         on: this.genActivatorListeners(),
>         attrs: this.genActivatorAttributes(),
>       })) || []
>
>       this.activatorNode = node
>
>       return node
>     }
> ```

---

### Some insight:

---

It is useful if you want to abstract components and pass down multiple listeners at once instead of writing multiple lines of assignments.

---

Consider a component:

```js
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      on: {
        click: console.log,
        contextmenu: console.log
      },
      value: "any key value pair"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="activator" :on="on" :otherSlotPropName="value" >
      <defaultComponent v-on="on" />
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

Given the component above, you can access the slot properties and pass them into your custom component:

```html
<ExampleComponent>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, otherSlotPropName }">
    <v-btn
      color="red lighten-2"
      dark
      v-on="on"
    >
      Click Me
    </v-btn>
  </template>
 <ExampleComponent />
```

---

#### Somethimes its easier to see it in plain javascript:

Comparing the component from above - with [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Slots) instead of template:

```
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      on: {
        click: console.log,
        contextmenu: console.log
      },
      value: "any key value pair"
    }
  },
  render(h){

    return h('div', [
      this.$scopedSlots.activator &&
      this.$scopedSlots.activator({
        on: this.on,
        otherSlotPropName: this.value
      })
      || h('defaultComponent', {
        listeners: this.on
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

#### In the source:

In case of a blank `v-on="eventsObject"` the method [`bindObjectListener`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/52719ccab8fccffbdf497b96d3731dc86f04c1ce/src/core/instance/render-helpers/bind-object-listeners.js#L5) will be called resulting in the assignment of the events to `data.on`.

This happens in the [`createComponent` scope](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b9de23b1008b52deca7e7df40843e318a42f3f53/src/core/vdom/create-component.js#L168).

Finaly the `listeners` are passed as `VNodeComponentOptions` and updated by [`updateListeners`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/6fe07ebf5ab3fea1860c59fe7cdd2ec1b760f9b0/src/core/vdom/helpers/update-listeners.js#L53).

---

#### Where Vue extends - the Vuetify implementation inspected:

When taking into account that one can join and extend vue instances, one can convince himself that any component can be reduced to a more atomic version.

This is what vuetify utilizes in the e.g. `v-dialog` component by creating a [`activator mixin`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3beea7c9107da273465b0d65f4cde3f8fbc1b7bc/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/activatable/index.ts#L20).

For now one can trace down the content of `on` mounted by the [`activatable`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/3beea7c9107da273465b0d65f4cde3f8fbc1b7bc/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/activatable/index.ts#L20):

```js
const simplyfiedActivable = {

  mounted(){
    this.activatorElement = this.getActivator()
  },
  watch{
    activatorElement(){
      // if is el?
      this.addActivatorEvents()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addActivatorEvents(){
      this.listeners = this.genActivatorListeners()
    },
    genActivatorListeners(){
      return {
        click: ...,
        mouseenter: ...,
        mouseleave: ...,
      }
    },
```

> ```
> genActivator () {
>       const node = getSlot(this, 'activator', Object.assign(this.getValueProxy(), {
>         on: this.genActivatorListeners(),
>         attrs: this.genActivatorAttributes(),
>       })) || []
>
>       this.activatorNode = node
>
>       return node
>     },
> ```

```
  }
}
```

With above snippet all there is left is to implement this into the actual component:

```
// vuetify usage/implemention of mixins 
const baseMixins = mixins(
  Activatable,
  ...other
)

const sympliefiedDialog = baseMixins.extend({
  ...options,
  render(h){
    
    const children = []
    children.push(this.genActivator())
    return h(root, ...options, children)
  }
})
```

---

Comment: i still don't get it :/

Comment: Basically, the pattern is to create a variable called `on` which is an object that holds all of the various event handlers. So instead of having to repeat `v-on:click="foo()"` and `v-on:contextmenu="bar()"` on a bunch of different components, you just say `v-on="on"` and they're all specified by what's in the `on` object. I guess it's a pattern/convention to call it that, but it's tough to find the definition of a two-letter variable name in a large application :/

Comment: I think they removed it, and now it's way easier to deal with `v-tooltip` with `props`, instead of `v-on`, https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/