# how to get param from url and display it in vue

Tags: vue.js

I have an url:
`http://localhost:8080/Currency?currency=RMB`
I want to get the currency param which is `RMB`

In:

```
created(){
    this.currencyParam = this.$route.query.currency;
    console.log(curr: ${this.currencyParam});
}
```

and I can get the `curr: RMB` in `F12 - console` but in `F12 -Vue` I get `currency:undefined`

In my template:

```
<template v-else>
          <gateway
            :currency="this.$route.query.currency"
          />
</template>
```

I get an error:

> Error in render: "**TypeError**: Cannot read property '$route' of undefined found in and in `F12 -Vue` I still get `currency:undefined`

Comment: No `this` in templates - just `$route...`

Comment: @Estradiaz I know it can solve, but why?

Comment: Some insight into reactivity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57615156/why-vue-change-specific-array-member-not-update-dom/57616094#57616094

Comment: The template parser got designed this way - as an example on v-on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524110/what-does-v-on-syntax-mean-in-vuejs/57524610#57524610

Comment: @Estradiaz can you help me with this pls?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676629/how-to-force-user-input-number-only-in-vue-numeric

Comment: @Estradiaz can you kindly put your answer into comment section? so that I can mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a watch property that will allow you to listen changes in query param

```js
data () {
  return {
   currencyParam = null
  }
},
watch: {
    '$route.query.currency': function () {
       if(this.$route && this.$route.query.currency) { // if not undefined
            console.log(`curr: ${this.$route.query.currency}`);
            this.currencyParam = this.$route.query.currency;
       }
    }
  }
```

Also change your template like this;

```js
<template>
   <gateway v-if="currencyParam" :currency="currencyParam" />
</template>
```