# how to force user input number only in <vue-numeric>

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

In my `<vue-numeric>`

```
<vue-numeric
      currency="RMB"
      separator=","
      v-bind:minus="false"
      v-model="amount"
      v-bind:precision="2"
      class="form-control form-control-lg bg-secondary border-0 text-white"
    ></vue-numeric>
```

By using this code it can convert the user input to `number` type even the input contains `string` inside, but what I want is user only can insert `number`and when alphabet pressed, it will display nothing

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a keydown event listener and test the keycode to see if it's a number:

`@keydown="testNumber"`

```
methods: {
  testNumber({ keyCode }) {
    if(keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is extend/ overwrite the component options - e.g.:

```
import VueNumeric from "vue-numeric";
const inputHanlder = VueNumeric.methods["onInputHandler"];
VueNumeric.methods["onInputHandler"] = function(val) {
  // here the sanitizer
  this.amount = this.amountNumber;
  inputHanlder.bind(this)();
};
VueNumeric.watch["valueNumber"] = function(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
  if (this.$refs.numeric !== document.activeElement) {
    this.amount = this.format(newValue);
  } else {
    this.amount = newValue;
  }
};
export default VueNumeric;
```