# How to Show buttons just when the mouse is hovering the table using Vuetify Data table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am new to start and working on Vue.js with Vuetify . Here i am used v-data-table component for displaying table data.
 Is there an option that when user go over (hover) the table with the mouse he could see the buttons in the table? or if i select row hide row values on displaying buttons. if i select multiple then we need to show the buttons on table header part(like header titles disable show the buttons.) i shared image like this.
enter image description here[image: ![enter image description here][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO0F3.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO0F3.jpg)

Comment: v-table takes a `#item` slot where you can customize the row layout - thus add `@mouseover` event

Comment: can u share   me the brief explanation

Comment: i have done something that might give you some understanding in slot mechanism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57524610/11204469  -- there is also an example on vuetify docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#customizing-default-rows

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I would do it, using

```
 <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
     <tbody>
         <tr
           v-for="item in items"
           :key="item.id"
           :search="search"
           @mouseover="selectItem(item)"
           @mouseleave="unSelectItem()"
         >
             <td>
                 <v-checkbox
                    multiple
                    v-model="selected"
                    :value="item"
                    style="margin:0px;padding:0px"
                    hide-details
                  />
             </td>
             <td> {{ item.one }}</td>
             <td> {{ item.two }}</td>
             <td> {{ item.three }}</td>
             <td>
                 <div v-if="item === selectedItem">
                     <v-btn>click</v-btn>
                 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</template>
```

https://codepen.io/TamerKhraisha/pen/BaaRqGo

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but in case someone still has this issue like me, this can be solved using simple CSS in your component file.

Wrap your action buttons in a div or similar and give it a className, ex. "actionButtons".

```html
<v-data-table 
  ...
 >
  <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
    <div class="actionButtons">
      // Your action buttons here
    </div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Then change the visibility on tr:hover like so;

```css
tr .actionButtons {
  visibility: hidden;
}

tr:hover .actionButtons {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Note that using visibility instead of display will prevent jumping in the content of the table, since the actions are there semantically, just hidden.

For future reference - a mouse-event feature is as of writing this post in a PR for Vue 2 (https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/15617)