# Vue.js pass a callback as prop to child component and execute on parent when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to create a dropdown component, in which it receives various data and the list items are built dynamically, but I am having difficulty detecting the click on any item in the list

parent

```
<Dropdown
  :items="[
    {
      text: 'Edit',
      icon: 'fal fa-edit',
      click: editFunction(id)
    },
    {
      text: 'Delete',
      icon: 'fal fa-trash-alt',
      click: deleteFunction(id)
    }
  ]"
/>
```

child `Dropdown.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="trigger">
      <i class="far fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
    </a>

    <ul class="items">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" class="item">
        <a>
          <i :class="item.icon"></i>
          {{ item.text }}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

currently in this way, as soon as the parent component is created,  the `editFunction(id)` and `deleteFunction(id)` methods are executed.

I know it's possible because [vuetifyjs](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/buttons/simple/dropdown.vue) it does that way, but I tried to inspect the source code but I got nowhere.

Comment: just bind `@click="item.click"` to the listener ,  did something once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524110/what-does-v-on-syntax-mean-in-vuejs/57524610#57524610

Comment: @Estradiaz and how can I pass the id as a parameter?

Comment: Wrap it? ()=> fn(id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done by

```
parent.vue 

<child-componet :parent-method="thisIsTheMethod" />

...

methods: {
      thisIsTheMethod()
           {
              //here it does something
           } 
     }
```

note that the method passed inside the prop does not have the parenthesis `()` because you are passing a reference to it.

To use it inside the child component add the ()

```
@click="parentMethod()"
```

To go back to your example, change this:

```
<Dropdown
  :items="[
    {
      text: 'Edit',
      icon: 'fal fa-edit',
      click: editFunction(id)
    },
    {
      text: 'Delete',
      icon: 'fal fa-trash-alt',
      click: deleteFunction(id)
    }
  ]"
/>
```

to

```
<Dropdown
  :items="[
    {
      text: 'Edit',
      icon: 'fal fa-edit',
      click: () => editFunction(10)
    },
    {
      text: 'Delete',
      icon: 'fal fa-trash-alt',
      click: () => deleteFunction(20)
    }
  ]"
/>
```

and leave your `editFunction(id)` method declaration as is. The argument will be automatically injected.

Despite this solution would work, the best way to achieve this communication between parent and child would be to emit the value in the child and then listen for it

Comment: `@click="parentMethod()"` recebo este erro `parentMethod is not a function`
could show how it would look in the child component?

furthermore, imagine that I am doing the user list, I will build a list using v-for and then `<Dropdown />` will be created dynamically, how would I know which user was clicked if I am not passing id as parameter?

Comment: You have to define parentMethod in the props

Comment: You have to pass the id parameter, inside the child. I wrote it

Comment: edited your answer so that we can pass the id parameter still in the parent component, it is impractical to do that child

Answer (score 0):

there have betters ways to do it, but about your idea should be as below:

```js
Vue.component('dropdown', {
  template: '#dropdown-template',
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      users: [
        { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
        { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    editFunction(id) {
      console.warn('edit item ' + id)
    },
    deleteFunction(id) {
      console.warn('delete item ' + id)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table border="1">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>name</th>
         <th>actions</tr>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <dropdown
              :items="[
                {
                  text: 'Edit',
                  icon: 'fal fa-edit',
                  event: 'edit-function'
                },
                {
                  text: 'Delete',
                  icon: 'fal fa-trash-alt',
                  event: 'delete-function'
                }
              ]"
              @edit-function="editFunction(user.id)"
              @delete-function="deleteFunction(user.id)"     
            />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="dropdown-template">
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="trigger">
    <i class="far fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
  </a>

  <ul class="items">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" class="item">
      <a @click="$emit(item.event)">
        <i :class="item.icon"></i>
        {{ item.text }}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: i guess than scoped slots should be the correct way